# Why is MATLAB out of memory when I have plenty of memory available?

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have a 272 million line uint8 vector loaded into my MATLAB workspace as variable "rawdata". No memory issues thus far. I am running on a 32-bit Dell with 4 GB RAM.

When I type "memory" in the command window I get this:

```
Maximum possible array: 480 MB
Memory available for all arrays: 1197 MB
Memory used by MATLAB: 581 MB
Physical Memory (RAM): 3241 MB
```

Now I type this:

```
rawdata = rawdata(800:end);
```

And I get an "Out of Memory" error.

Also, if I do this

```
rawdata(1:799) = [];
```

I get the same Out of Memory error.

I clearly have plenty of memory to spare. The rawdata variable is only ~300 MB.

**Can anyone explain why the commands "`rawdata = rawdata(800:end)`" or "`rawdata(1:799)=[]`" are so memory intensive?**

Thanks

Comment: For the latter question, MATLAB is not storing the same array twice. Because the array is unchanged it's going to be stored as a reference until you make changes to it. You can see this behavior with `A = rawdata; A(end) = [];`, which will probably give you an OOM error.

Comment: Thanks! I edited that portion out of the question.

Comment: Can you include the output of this command to be clear on the size of the array?: `whos rawdata`

Comment: From playing around this seems like an internal MATLAB issue. I can't reproduce any significant memory change with `rawdata = rawdata(800:end);` but there is a significant memory spike with `rawdata(1:799) = [];` (close to 6 gigs on my machine). This seems to be mainly related to `uint8`, a `double` array seems to be just duplicated in memory for the `rawdata(1:799) = [];`. This is still undesirable but at least makes some sense. I'm going to write this up and submit it to TMW.

Comment: This also means I've conflated two different things in my initial comment. The reference vs. duplication story is still the same but `A = ones(10000000, 1); B = A; B(end) = 2;` is a better visualization.

Comment: This is most definitely a bug.  Many of us in the MATLAB chatroom on SO have confirmed this behaviour.  We're not sure what's happening, but we're thinking of filing a bug report.